# How to prepare a setup project which includes IIS deploy and db creation

Tags: iis, deployment, installation, installshield, setup-project

I have a project which has WCF Rest Service, Web app (Angular 2.x),Desktop App (WinForm) and Sql Server Db.
I don't want to deal with setup for every customers. I want to plan every deployment step and create a setup project to apply these steps.

Steps:

1. Run Sql script to create db and tables. (Setup project should ask Sql-Server Login Information)
2. Deploy WCF Rest Service On IIS with selected port. Set Service's Application pool 32 bit enabled. (Setup project should ask port)
3. Deploy Web App On IIS with selected port.(Setup project should ask port)
4. Deploy ClickOnce Desktop App On IIS with selected port.(Setup project should ask port)

Can i achieve this using InstallShield or is there another third party application? As an another option i can develope a project to apply this steps using a library if exists.

Comment: I'd love to help but there are a couple dozens questions in this.  Even with expert knowledge and existing snippets to pull from this is about 20-40 hours of work.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherPainter for your interest. Actually i am new on this subject. If you can show me a roadmap, i can keep going. I wonder this job can accomplish via InstallShield. Also i found a deployment tool which is called [Octopus](https://octopus.com/). Which 3rd part app or library should i focus?